# Track Click-to-Call Popup Actions as Google Analytics Events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick

I've this button that shows an option to call upon click. I'm already tracking using Google Analytics how many people are clicking on it. But is there anyway to track buttons that show up after the click and if people actually clicked on "Call" or "Cancel" ?? [image]

```
 <input onclick="change()" class="btn btn-primary phone" type="button" value="Show Phone Number" id="myButton1" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function change() 
  {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
    elem.value = "" + {{clinic.contact_no}};
    ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Number', 'click','Dr.{{doctor.name}}');

  if (window.mobileAndTabletcheck() == true){
            document.location.href = 'tel:+974{{clinic.contact_no}}'
        }
  }


  </script>
```

Comment: just put event listeners on the call popup buttons just like you did with the change function

Comment: The code looks fine, except for the label you are using. The label may show up as "Dr.{{doctor.name}}" with the variable in the curly braces not being evaluated.

Comment: @amirbar Could you elaborate? How do I id them?

Comment: you didnt gave the code that create that popup so I cant help

Comment: @amirbar Sorry i forgot to add the actual line for call to phone action. I've updated the code.

Comment: oh, pretty sure you cant know. you can have a assertion of "if after tel: clicked the user was active in 5 seconds than I can say he didnt call" but the reverse dosent work like: if someone wasent active for 20 seconds maybe he just clicked cancel and closed the browser...

Comment: Do not send personally Identifiable information to Google Analytics. It is a violation of the TOS http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html